# BOOTSTRAP: rearrange order of different sized panels on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem on how to rearrange my panels on mobile.
The panels have different sizes.
Pls see attach for the screenshot of the page in large screen (col-lg):

[image: page in large panel]

EDIT: The large screen layout is ok, since I don't want any spaces between rows because the panels are different in heights.

When I view it on mobile (col-xs), I get:
1st panel
4th panel
7th panel
2nd panel
5th panel
3rd panel
6th panel

Pls see image for the mobile screen:

[image: page in mobile screen]

I want to rearrange the locations of the panels in mobile (col-xs), so the arrangement would be like this:
1st panel
2nd panel
3rd panel
4th panel
7th panel
5th panel
6th panel

Pls see code snippet for my codes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">

<!-- 1st panel -->  
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">1st</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        1st panel<br>
        1st panel<br>
        1st panel
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- 4th panel -->  
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">4th</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
     4th panel<br>
     4th panel<br>
     4th panel<br>
     4th panel<br>
      </div>
    </div>   
<!-- 7th panel -->  
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">7th</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
     7th panel<br>
     7th panel<br>
     7th panel<br>
     7th panel<br>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   
<!-- 2nd panel -->  
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">2nd</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        2nd panel<br>
        2nd panel<br>
        2nd panel<br>
        2nd panel<br>
        2nd panel<br>
        2nd panel    
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- 5th panel -->  
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">5th</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
     5th panel<br>
     5th panel<br>
     5th panel<br>
     5th panel<br>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  
<!-- 3rd panel -->  
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">3rd</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
     3rd panel<br>
     3rd panel<br>
     3rd panel  
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- 6th panel -->  
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">6th</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
     6th panel<br>
     6th panel<br>
     6th panel<br>
     6th panel<br>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
    
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow Bootstrap grid system and options. I think using that you can solve your problem.

[Link for Grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

[Link for Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

There are predefined sizes for devices. So, you can make every div, etc all devices compatible.

Comment: Thanks for answering my problem. I already read the links and I don't think they have the answer for my problem,

Answer (score 0):

If you want two different sets of arrangements in large devices and extrasmall devices, you need to have two different sets of codes (since you are changing the order of the "div"s altogether, the grid system won't come to any aid.)

In bootstrap, you can pull or push columns. But rows cannot be moved based on devices.

For the specification you are wanting, What you can do is add the same code twice with visibility filtering-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">

<!-- Only for large devices, will be visible only in large devices --> 
<!-- 1st panel -->      
            <div class="col-lg-4 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">1st</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    1st panel<br>
                    1st panel<br>
                    1st panel
                  </div>
                </div>
<!-- 4th panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">4th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    4th panel<br>
                    4th panel<br>
                    4th panel<br>
                    4th panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>          
<!-- 7th panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">7th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    7th panel<br>
                    7th panel<br>
                    7th panel<br>
                    7th panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>


<!-- 2nd panel -->      
            <div class="col-lg-4 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">2nd</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel    
                  </div>
                </div>
<!-- 5th panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">5th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    5th panel<br>
                    5th panel<br>
                    5th panel<br>
                    5th panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<!-- 3rd panel -->      
            <div class="col-lg-4 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">3rd</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    3rd panel<br>
                    3rd panel<br>
                    3rd panel  
                  </div>
                </div>
<!-- 6th panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">6th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    6th panel<br>
                    6th panel<br>
                    6th panel<br>
                    6th panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

<!-- Only for extra small devices, will be visible only in mobile device -->


            <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">       
<!-- 1st panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">1st</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    1st panel<br>
                    1st panel<br>
                    1st panel
                  </div>
                </div>
<!-- 4th panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">4th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    4th panel<br>
                    4th panel<br>
                    4th panel<br>
                    4th panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>          
<!-- 7th panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">7th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    7th panel<br>
                    7th panel<br>
                    7th panel<br>
                    7th panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>

<!-- 2nd panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">2nd</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel    
                  </div>
                </div>
<!-- 5th panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">5th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    5th panel<br>
                    5th panel<br>
                    5th panel<br>
                    5th panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>

<!-- 3rd panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">3rd</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    3rd panel<br>
                    3rd panel<br>
                    3rd panel  
                  </div>
                </div>
<!-- 6th panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">6th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    6th panel<br>
                    6th panel<br>
                    6th panel<br>
                    6th panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I really appreciate it.

I don't want to add the same code twice for different devices, since I'll be revising the contents from time to time, and I think it will be difficult to do so in the future if I will change 2 codes. 

I also tried push and pull but no luck. The arrangement becomes weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this if it suits for your design

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">

<!-- 1st panel -->      
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">1st</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    1st panel<br>
                    1st panel<br>
                    1st panel
                  </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
<!-- 4th panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">2nd</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel<br>
                    2nd panel    
                  </div>
                </div>  
    </div>
<!-- 7th panel -->  <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">3rd</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    3rd panel<br>
                    3rd panel<br>
                    3rd panel<br>
                    3rd panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>
</div>
            </div>
<div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">4th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    4th panel<br>
                    4th panel<br>
                    4th panel
                  </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
<!-- 4th panel -->      
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">5th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    5th panel<br>
                    5th panel<br>
                    5th panel<br>
                    5th panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>  
    </div>
<!-- 7th panel -->  <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">6th</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    6th panel<br>
                    6th panel<br>
                    6th panel<br>
                    6th panel<br>
                  </div>
                </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">7st</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    7th panel<br>
                    7th panel<br>
                    7th panel
                  </div>
                </div>


</div>

        </div>          


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I really appreciate it. I tried this but I have different sized panels, I don't want any upper space between rows on larger screens (just like the first attachment on the description).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding all your `.panel` elements to a `.col-md-12` div in descending order. This will give you the desired layout on medium sized screens.

Adding a media query for large sized screens at the default bootstrap `col-lg-*` breakpoint at `1200px` with a flexbox layout and `flex-direction` set to `row` will take care of the desired layout with descending order from left to right on large screens.

Here is an example. You may also want to check out [**can i use flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).
For browsers that do not support flexbox there are lots of fallback solutions on the internet.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .lg-flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .panel {
    flex: 0 1 32%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- 1st panel -->  
    <div class="col-md-12 lg-flex-row">

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">1st</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          1st panel<br />
          1st panel<br />
          1st panel
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 2n panel -->  
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">2nd</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          2nd panel<br />
          2nd panel<br />
          2nd panel<br />
          2nd panel<br />
          2nd panel<br />
          2nd panel
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 3rd panel -->  
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">3rd</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          3rd panel<br />
          3rd panel<br />
          3rd panel
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 4th panel -->  
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">4th</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          4th panel<br />
          4th panel<br />
          4th panel<br />
          4th panel
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 5th panel -->  
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">5th</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          5th panel<br />
          5th panel<br />
          5th panel<br />
          5th panel
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 6th panel -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">6th</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          5th panel<br />
          5th panel<br />
          5th panel<br />
          5th panel
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 7th panel -->  
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">7th</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          5th panel<br />
          5th panel<br />
          5th panel<br />
          5th panel
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. But for large screens, I don't want any spaces between rows, just like the one I attached on the first image (e.g. no space between 1st panel and 4th panel)